# NGXS: Property 'stream$' is used before its initialization

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

At first glance, it seems a default behavior of angular component life cycle logic that because of component properties did not initialized yet so stream$ cannot have assignment before component initialization complete:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `<p>app works!</p>`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @Select(AppState.getItems)
  stream$: Observable<string[]>;

  firstItemStream$: Observable<{ selectedItem: string }> = this.stream$ // error occurs here
  .pipe(
    find(({ itemId }) => itemId === 0),
  );

  ...
```

Quoted from NgXs:

> APP_INITIALIZER is resolved after NGXS states are initialized. They are initialized by the NgxsModule that is imported into the AppModule. The ngxsOnInit method on states is also invoked before the APP_INITIALIZER token is resolved.

Above code works as expected but typescript error still occurs. Is there any workaround from this?

Also I decided to not open an issue to typescript opensource project because of it might also be about NgXs lifecycle itself.

Comment: Not clear what typescript error you are seeing, but it sounds like this scenario for using [select decorator](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select#using-select-decorator-with-strictpropertyinitialization).  So you'd need update the declaration to `@Select(AppState.getItems) stream$!: Observable<string[]>;`

Comment: @GarthMason you're right. This is a workaround yet it is not a eligible typescript way I think. Still, it is an acceptable answer. can you also post your proposal as answer so I can assign as a right answer?

Comment: Sure mate, will do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like [this](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select#using-select-decorator-with-strictpropertyinitialization) scenario for using select decorator.

So you'd need update the declaration to:

`@Select(AppState.getItems) stream$!: Observable<string[]>;`

Comment: Also this issue doesn't occur minor versions of typescript 4+

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `stream$` inside the `.ts` code as another source, you need to define the property like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `<p>app works!</p>`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  stream$: Observable<string[]>;
  firstItemStream$: Observable<{selectedItem: string}>;

  constructor(private readonly _store: Store) {
    this.stream$ = this.store.select(AppState.getItems);
    this.firstItemStream$ = this.stream$
      .pipe(
        find(({itemId}) => itemId === 0),
      );
  }
}
```

Note: I assume `AppState.getItems` is a pure function that receives a state and returns a given substate.

Here's [the documentation](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select#store-select-function).

Comment: Yes, I know that. But why select decorator works as in traditional way?

Comment: The error occurs because when the code gets executed the `stream$` prop is not yet initialized, thus causing an error when being accessed. The example above the linked one shows how to use the decorator if no other property relies on it.